# groupby in userdefined python function, doesn't work

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have made my own userdefined function in Python. The input are some parameters and a dataframe. First some new variables are added to the input dataframe. Then I try to make a groupby on the dataframe and left join the result on to the dataframe.

But the dataframe don't get the groupby variables added.

```
 def test(df, params):

    df['b']=df['a']*params['some_parameter']
    df['c']=df['b']*df['total']

    aaa=df.groupby(['aa', 'bb']).agg({'c':'sum'})
    df=pd.merge(df,a,how='left',on=['aa', 'bb'])

    return
```

Next try:

```
def test(df, params):

df['b']=df['a']*params['some_parameter']
df['d']=df['c']*df['b']

aaa=df.groupby(['y','x']).agg({'d':'sum','g':'sum'}).add_suffix('_sum')
df=df.join(aaa, on=['y','x'])    

return
```

I then call the function by:
test(df2,params)

I would expect df2 would have 4 new columns, b, d, d_sum and g_sum. But it only has 2 new columns, b and d.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) instaed `groupby` with left join by `merge`:

```
aaa=df.groupby(['aa', 'bb']).agg({'c':'sum'})
df=pd.merge(df,a,how='left',on=['aa', 'bb'])
```

to:

```
df['c1'] = df.groupby(['aa', 'bb'])['c'].transform('sum')
```

All together:

```
def test(df, params):

    df['b']=df['a']*params['some_parameter']
    df['c']=df['b']*df['total']

    df['new'] = df.groupby(['aa', 'bb'])['c'].transform('sum')

    return df
```

If need aggregate multiple columns is possible use [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) with default left join:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
         'x':list('dddddd'),
         'y':list('aaabbb'),
         'a':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
         'b':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
         'c':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
         'd':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
         'g':[1,3,6,4,4,3],
})

print (df)
   x  y  a  b  c  d  g
0  d  a  4  7  1  5  1
1  d  a  5  8  3  3  3
2  d  a  4  9  5  6  6
3  d  b  5  4  7  9  4
4  d  b  5  2  1  2  4
5  d  b  4  3  0  4  3
```

---

```
params = {'some_parameter':100}

def test(df, params):

    df['b']=df['a']*params['some_parameter']
    df['d']=df['c']*df['b']

    aaa=df.groupby(['y','x']).agg({'d':'sum','g':'sum'}).add_suffix('_sum')
    df=df.join(aaa, on=['y','x'])    

    return df

df1 = test(df, params)
print (df1)
   x  y  a    b  c     d  g  d_sum  g_sum
0  d  a  4  400  1   400  1   3900     10
1  d  a  5  500  3  1500  3   3900     10
2  d  a  4  400  5  2000  6   3900     10
3  d  b  5  500  7  3500  4   4000     11
4  d  b  5  500  1   500  4   4000     11
5  d  b  4  400  0     0  3   4000     11
```

Comment: It doesn't work. When i do it outside of a function, it works. But when I move it inside the function, the 2 new columns is not in the dataframe. I have pasted in the new function in the original post.

Comment: @thomlund83 - There is some error? So if working outside function there should be problem inside. Is possible share your function, which not working by edit question?

Comment: @thomlund83 - do you forget `return df` ?

Comment: "return df" does not help. I guess its not needed since the b and c variables ARE created in the dataframe df2

Comment: @thomlund83 - You are wrong, is necessary `return df`, added samle data function to my answer - working nice with `return df`